# clearfix doesn't work in angularJs

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

```html
<ul class="dropdown-menu wm_search_div" ng-show="searchDivShow">
    <li ng-repeat="user in searchUserList">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="wm_clearfix3">
            <img ng-src="{{user.faceIcon}}" class="pull-left wm_search_uface"/>
            <div class="pull-left wm_ml5">
                <div class="wm_search_uname" ng-bind="user.username"></div>
                <span ng-bind="'账号：'+user.account" class="wm_search_uacc"></span>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="wm_clearfix3">
             <img ng-src="resources/images/default_faceicon.jpg" class="pull-left wm_search_uface"/>
             <div class="pull-left wm_ml5">
                  <div class="wm_search_uname">fdsfsfds</div>
                  <span class="wm_search_uacc">fsdfds</span>
             </div>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

```css
.wm_clearfix3{
    overflow: auto;
    height: 1%;
}
```

I added a clearfix css class in my  label,and it was working well when I had not add angular codes into my HTML.But when I added angular into HTML,the clearfix class became don't work.The cut picture like this:

[image]

[image]

Maybe because of 'ng-repeat'?Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add `ng-class` unless you are adding a class with logic. So just add `class` is enough

Comment: Yes,ng-class is not necessary,and I have changed 'ng-class' to 'class',but clearfix still doesn't work.

Comment: I think the problem is with your .wm_clearfix3 . Do you use :before & :after??

Comment: .wm_clearfix1{
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.wm_clearfix2{
    height:1%;
}
.wm_clearfix2::after{
    content:".";
    display:block;
    height:0;
    clear:both;
    visibility:hidden;
}
.wm_clearfix3{
    overflow: auto;
    height: 1%;
}
.wm_clearfix4{
    overflow: hidden;
    zoom: 1;
}             I have four clearfix class and I have tryed everyone.All of them  worked well without angular.

Answer (score 0):

Why use 'ng-class' if you have not an angular expression ?
try with:

```
ng-class="{wm_clearfix3}"
```

or:

```
.wm_clearfix3{
  overflow: auto;
  height: 1%;
  clear: both;
}
```

Comment: I tryed with 'class' rather than 'ng-class',but 'class' doesn't work .

Comment: try to insert an empty div after your span tag, like:
`<div class='wm_clearfix3'></div>`

and:
`.wm_clearfix3{  clear: both; }`

Comment: This also doesn't work.And I have update my description codes and cut pictures,maybe you can see the problem more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Does the solution at the below JSFiddle link help you out at all?

https://jsfiddle.net/6vm4csjb/

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

[class*="wm_clearfix"] {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

[class*="wm_clearfix"]:before, [class*="wm_clearfix"]:after {
  display: table;
  content: " ";
}

img {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

.pull-left {
  float: left;
}

<ul class="dropdown-menu wm_search_div" ng-show="searchDivShow">
  <li ng-repeat="user in searchUserList">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="wm_clearfix3">
      <img ng-src="{{user.faceIcon}}" class="pull-left wm_search_uface"/>
      <div class="pull-left wm_ml5">
        <div class="wm_search_uname" ng-bind="user.username"></div>
        <span ng-bind="'账号：'+user.account" class="wm_search_uacc"></span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="wm_clearfix3">
      <img ng-src="resources/images/default_faceicon.jpg" class="pull-left wm_search_uface"/>
      <div class="pull-left wm_ml5">
        <div class="wm_search_uname">fdsfsfds</div>
        <span class="wm_search_uacc">fsdfds</span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I tryed it just now,but it is not a good solution.Thanks at all!